# Converting array into object of array in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a state of empty array x=[]
I am getting response of array of string of from api like `["a","b","c"]`
I want my state to be like `[{row:"a"},{row:"b"},{row:"c"}]`

Answer (score 1):

You can transform the element in array using `map` function

```js
> ["a","b","c"].map(row => ({ row }))

[{row:"a"},{row:"b"},{row:"c"}]
```